# version_compare indicating x.y.0 is higher than x.y?

Tags: php, compare

Why does

`version_compare('3.8.0', '3.8', '>')`

return `true`?

In terms of versioning, one would expect both to be identical, but `version_compare` indicates that 3.8.0 is higher than 3.8. Is there any workaround for this weird behaviour?

Running PHP 5.2.17

Answer (score -2):

From the top of my head it feels that it could be that 3.8.0 > 3.8 since you have to imagine a regular charting  x,y graph...it's a 2 dimension chart.... but it could be that  if you add a 0 to the x,y axis you get a 3 dimesional chart i.e. a higher type of expression than just the 2D one...
That is the only logical explaination I could make from it...but maybe I am crazy : ) ...and that's fine... better crazy than stuck up : )

Yours Truly
kevin
 01001100010011110101011001000101 to  googolplex